# how to frequently update a ui element (text view)

Tags: android

while trying to create a app I found that if I try to run a function like:

```
    int i = 1;
    String s = "";

    while(true)
    {
text.setText(sint.valueOf(i)
i=i+1;
    }
```

where text is a text view
and the function is called by a button's On Click Listener the app gets stuck insted of incrementing the value of the text view on the screen

is there a way to make this work without setting delays or with minimal delays

and if so id like an example

Comment: you do realize this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the int variable in your Activity (or Fragment, or whatever) and then on each click increment the value and set it to the `TextView`. What you are doing doesn't work because your while loop is infinite and it runs on the UI thread so it blocks the UI and the `TextView` never gets a chance to update.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int counter;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(++counter));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if I understood what you're trying to achieve here, but try this. The idea is, you have a Thread that increments the counter FAST, and then you have an animation that update the TextView, it will try to do so at 60fps so it's gonna skip a lot of numbers. There is no way you can update the counter that fast and at the same time update the TextView at each increment. This looks like a complete nonsense to me but it's fun to watch the number growing that fast :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int counter;
    private TextView textView;
    boolean running;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Animation animation = new Animation(){
                    @Override
                    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                        textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    }
                };
                animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                textView.startAnimation(animation);         
                new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        running = true;
                        while(running)
                            counter++;
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want it to increment fom the loop and i want to do it as fast as possible

Comment: so basically you want that once the user clicks the TextView the counter starts growing (1,2,3,4..) and the textView shows the value?

Comment: of course it does, I think you might want to spawn a Thread and increment the counter there, then update the TextView

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: of course, but there is a problem: if you increment the counter in the while loop it will be VERY fast, updating the TextView will be slower so you will not see all the numbers, you might see for example 1 and then 100 and then 200

Comment: im trying to write "that's ok" but the app wats more then 15 characters so... : ) (just ignore everything not in quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a method like this

```
private void updateTxt(String newText) {
    txt.setText(newText);
}
```

and call this method when you need to update your `TextView`

Comment: what is the difference between calling the method and adding the methods code inside the loop?